# Enabling Wireguard using wg-quick blocks connections from another subnet

Tags: networking, routing, wireguard

I've managed to set up Wireguard using `wg-quick` running as a service on Ubuntu 20.04. Wireguard is connected to a VPN service provider and it works just fine. LAN access to and from the Ubuntu machine from other machines on the same subnet (`10.0.100.0/24`) also works fine when Wireguard is running. However, once Wireguard is brought up (using `wg-quick up wg0`) connectivity is lost with other subnets.

To elaborate, the other subnet in question is for a different VPN connection used for connections to the LAN through a firewall. The firewall takes care of routing between machines on the LAN in subnet `10.0.100.0/24` and machines on the VPN in subnet `10.88.220.0/24`. In the absence of Wireguard, everything works swimmingly and all machines on the LAN can be accessed by a machine on the VPN. But once Wireguard is brought up, that connection disappears.

I've reviewed the man page for `wg-quick` and have reviewed quite a few posts on how to configure Wireguard but haven't been able to figure out a solution. Amongst the things I've tried were to add the `PostUp = ip route add 10.88.220.0/24 dev eth0` to `/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf`. In reviewing the commands executed by `wg-quick`, I suspect my issue has something to do with some of the ip commands executed by `wg-quick` - specifically:

```
[#] ip -4 rule add not fwmark 51820 table 51820
[#] ip -4 rule add table main suppress_prefixlength 0
```

My understanding is that these commands (in combination with some others) create a separate routing table that points to `wg0` as the default, then diverts traffic other than LAN traffic to be routed thought that table. I imagine what is happening is that traffic that is supposed to be going to `10.88.220.0/24` though `eth0` is instead being redirected by the rules above to table 81820 and going out on `wg0`. I also tried adding `PostUp = ip route add 10.88.220.0/24 dev eth0 table 51820` just to see if that might work (but understanding that it's not a permanent solution as the number changes from session to session), but perhaps not surprisingly it didn't.

I've tried reviewing the pages for the `ip route` and `ip rule` commands, but haven't been able to figure out how to modify or supplement the rules and/or routing tables to re-enable connection between the LAN and the VPN. Any advice or suggestions on how this might be done would be most appreciated.

Comment: Most likely the problem is that your "other VPN" is cut off because its encapsulated traffics are routed into the wireguard tunnel (due to the the fact that the default route, i.e. route with the prefix of `/0`, is overridden by the wireguard magic you quoted above). You'll need to add an ip rule (with lower priority number / higher priority) to make your "other VPN" an exception (e.g. `iif lo ipproto $other_vpn_tcp_or_udp sport $other_vpn_listening_port table main).

Comment: Hey thanks for your thoughts Tom. To clarify a bit, the other VPN creates a tunnel between the remote machine and the firewall. Once packets hit the firewall, they are decrypted and go on their merry way, I believe. What I'm struggling with is the suppress_prefixlength rule, I think. My understanding is that that rule means that default (/0) rules in table main are ignored. But If I add "ip route add 10.88.220.0/24 dev eth0" then shouldn't that route still apply? As noted above, I also tried adding it to 51820 and that didn't work either.

Comment: Honestly, I've no idea what "firewall" (or "remote machine") you are talking about, and firewall does not take care of routing (unless you are talking about some forwarding device that acts also as a firewall for some hosts). What *I* was talking about is, your concern shouldn't be the route for the IP subnet used by the other VPN, but the route for remote endpoint of it. Perhaps you should include in your question the `ip r` output (without the wireguard service running) and what implementation is the other VPN (e.g. OpenVPN?), which would allow easier communication.

Comment: Also if `10.88.220.0/24` is an IP subnet used by/for a VPN, then the right `dev` could hardly be `eth0` anyway.

Comment: OK, thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The fix was embarrassingly simple. All I needed to to was to add `via [gateway]` to the first rule I had tried:

```
PostUp = ip route add 10.88.220.0/24 dev eth0 via 10.0.100.1
```